# How to change title format for HTML files generated by doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to generate documentation from Matlab files like this

```
%> @file fooBar.m
%> @ingroup KEK
%> @brief Documentation file example.
```

Now title is this

> fooBar.m File Reference

But I need this

> fooBar Reference

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Which output format? Matlab is not supported directly by doxygen, how do you generate the documentation here? The "File Reference" is set by doxygen automatically (see e.g. `translator_en.h`) and can only be changed by either: creating an own version of doxygen and modifying the string here or by postprocessing the resulting output (this cannot be done inside doxygen and has to be done outside of doxygen).

Comment: @alber Doxygen version 1.9.2
For Matlab support I am using [m2cpp.pl](https://github.com/simgunz/doxymatlab/blob/master/m2cpp.pl).
Output format is HTML.